# Unable to decrypt .PEM in Powershell, but can in AWS Console

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, rsa

We are storing the content of a our .AWS .PEM key in a password manager utility.

We are using PowerShell to automate the building of our servers.

Currently I am attempting to pull the password from the password manager, and create a .PEM key. Once I am done with it, it is deleted immediately.

Here is my code:

```
   try
    {
        //pulling the key!

        $password = $mypulledkey
    }
    catch{}

    $password | Out-File -Encoding ascii C:\scripts\Amazon\ops.pem 

    return New-Object -TypeName psobject $creds
```

The code here pretty much follows the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-ec2-keypairs.html) in regards to creating the .pem key.

When once the key is created, I can manually go into an instance and decrypt the key just fine to get the Administrator password....

When I try to run the following via the AWSPowershell cmdlets:

```
$password = Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId "i-XXXXXXXXX" -PemFile C:\scripts\Amazon\ops.pem -Decrypt
```

I get an error saying:

```
Get-EC2PasswordData : Invalid RSA Private Key
```

Comment: The doc says to use `$myPSKeyPair.KeyMaterial | Out-File -Encoding ascii myPSKeyPair.pem`.  You should probably try `$password.KeyMaterial | Out-File -Encoding ascii C:\scripts\Amazon\ops.pem`

Comment: Invalid RSA Private Key sounds like you do not have access to the private key of the certificate that's being used to perform crypto functions, whereas the server you're running the AWS console on does have it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Invalid RSA Private Key' error means your private key is in incorrect format.

> Private key must begin with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and end with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Please double check that your PEM file is in the correct format. For example try to upload the file in AWS EC2 Console and see if you get any errors.

See also: [Windows Password won't decrypt on AWS EC2 even with the correct private key](https://serverfault.com/q/603984/130437).